# Meaning of ON at the end of a sentence

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

There is ON at the end of the following sentence.

> Remaining aloof was no longer safe under the restored democracy of 403 on.

403 is the year.

I think without it the sentence makes sense enough. I know there is no usual sentence that ends with a preposition and there is no object of it. If I understand it as an adverb I can't find any verb that matches it.

Does it have any special meaning? If so what does it?

Comment: It's hard to interpret, but I believe it means "from the year 403 and in years following 403".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the adverb (more usually "onwards" or "onward") indicating the direction in time from that specified in the sentence (403) or context (the restoration of [Athenian] democracy).

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/onwards

The sentence would be understood with "on" omitted, but the usage implies a *continuing* danger here, as opposed to a brief period during the restoration year/s.

https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/onwards